# yii 2.0 get logged in user's Session ID

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

Am new to Yii, this is the login function (path /basic/controllers/siteController.php), once the users is logged in it will render the login template.

After a user is logged in,

How to get the SESSION ID and store to DB. ?

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

And the model code (path /models/LoginForm.php)

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$session = Yii::$app->session->getId();
```

Will grab the Id. There is a good article on sessions here http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/session-handling-in-yii-framework-2-0/

And to save something like:

```
$model->session = $session;
$model->save();
```

Comment: while saving to DB i get this error Setting unknown property: app\models\LoginForm::session

Comment: Do you have a session attribute in the LoginForm model?